# SonarLint greatly slows down Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I recently switched to Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition) and installed SonarLint, hoping to synchronize my code analyzation settings with my Sonarqube. However, after installing the SonarLint integration in Visual Studio, I experienced a heavy slowdown of my IDE, inlcuding heavy stuttering and lagging. I have so far not even connected to my Sonarqube repository - the addon is simply loaded and - as far as I can tell - not used.

My specs are:

- i7-2620M
- 8GB RAM
- Windows 10 x64
- Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition
- ReSharper Ultimate 2016.1
- Productivity Power Tools 2015
- GhostDoc
- Code Contracts Tools

As soon as I disable the SonarLint plugin and restart Visual Studio, the IDE is reacting way smoother and stops acting sluggish.

Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: What size is the solution where you experience this lagging?

Comment: For this size of a solution, I think you you'll have to accept that analyzing the source code takes quite some time and processing power. You may want to try other static analyzer packages too. FxCop is also being ported to use the new compiler framework. You can try to add the new FxCop analyzers (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/1.2.0-beta2) to you projects and see that the problem is not specific to SonarLint.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be absolutely fine with this during the initial code analyzation. However, once my solution has been completely processed and no more warnings appear, I would expect the IDE behave smoothly again.

However, as soon as I start typing new code, the IDE freezes heavily again and stutters. Even simple statements like "var x = 0" might take anywhere between 1 and 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The SonarLint Visual Studio extension analyses your code even if you don't connect the solution to a SonarQube project. So it's expected that some processing is going on. We've experienced high memory usage with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, which is being or is already resolved by the Roslyn team.

SonarLint reports issues in the Error Window. You might want to have a look there, so that you see that SonarLint is reporting issues. All of our rules have IDs that start with a capital "S".

Comment: I'm indeed running Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. There are no errors being reported by SonarLint, however my warnings are continously increasing which seems to take up quite some processing power and memory due to the size of the solution and legacy code included.

Comment: Yes, by default SonarLint doesn't report errors just warnings, because we don't want to fail the build.

Comment: Just had the same experience with Visual Studio Code and disabled Sonarlint Extension. So the problem still exists in 2021.

Comment: Same behaviour exist on Windows definitely, meanwhile macos and linux are fine.